# uwsgi Exception: not correct domain name /

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have some application written in python. 
I'm trying to run python application under uwsgi.

My app.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir      = /var/www/myapp
wsgi-file  = /var/www/myapp/app.wsgi

uid        = apache
gid        = apache

master     = true
processes  = 1
socket     = :8080
vacuum     = true
```

Start uwsgi:

```
uwsgi --ini app.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from app.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.10 (64bit) on [Sat Mar 21 16:59:09 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) on 21 March 2015 16:55:47
os: Linux-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 30 12:09:22 UTC 2014
nodename: lw_site
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 8
current working directory: /var/www/myapp
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi
chdir() to /var/www/myapp
your processes number limit is 4096
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :8080 fd 3
Python version: 2.7.5 (default, Jun 17 2014, 18:11:42)  [GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x2644f70
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145520 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x2644f70 pid: 39838 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 39838)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 39839, cores: 1)
```

This is

```
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='')
```

confuse me.

I get this error:

```
Custom Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/myapp/app/manager.py", line 53, in app
    contrller, args = router.mapping(request, city_model)
  File "/var/www/myapp/app/router.py", line 478, in mapping
    raise Exception('not correct domain name '+str(rurl))
Exception: not correct domain name /
```

Where is I made a mistake ?

Comment: where can i find this error:

'Custom Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/myapp/app/manager.py", line 53, in app
    contrller, args = router.mapping(request, city_model)
  File "/var/www/myapp/app/router.py", line 478, in mapping
    raise Exception('not correct domain name '+str(rurl))
Exception: not correct domain name /'

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error. It's problem in code. It get domain name from SERVER_NAME variable. I set in nginx:

```
 uwsgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
```